# How can I evaluate SQLServer 2012 Standard Edition

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server-2012

"Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit)" was installed on my server by the hosting provider.

I'd like to downgrade to "Standard Evaluation Edition (64-bit)".

Does this even exist?

Answer (score 1):

I've not checked for this specific product yet, and I'm no SQL expert, but generally the differences between Standard & Enterprise are scalability and high availability.  Generally the products are the same other than that, so it may well be adequate to evaluate SQL 2012 using the enterprise version.

There's a list of features available in both [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions.aspx) - maybe just stick to using the standard features and ignore the enterprise ones?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The feature list is pretty wooly, there's a more detailed list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx , however, it's still pretty hard to tie the descriptions into specific API calls, etc.  I really need to try it for real.